# JBOSS 7 module class ignored by ejb in WEB-INF/lib jar during deploy of war

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss, annotations

Good day

I am tring to deploy a war file with inside an ejb.jar in WEB-INF/lib path 
i have also a jboss-deployment-structure.xml used to load a library stored in an external module.

**a war file**

```
WEB-INF
jboss-deployment-structure.xml 
WEB-INF/lib
WEB-INF/lib/ejb.jar
```

in *jboss-deployment-structure.xml* is define as follow

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>  
    <deployment >
        <dependencies>  
              <module name="my.module.A" />  
        </dependencies> 

    </deployment>  

</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

**ejb.jar** has a dependency with a **classA** stored in **my.module.A jar** 
but the deploy fails with a class not found

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try add export="true" to module dependency

```
<module name="my.module.A" export="true"/>
```